# Laravel 8 - back()->withInput() is empty

Tags: php, laravel

If I execute a `redirect () -> back () -> withInput ()` in my controller, I do not get an `old ()` value in my template. The -> with () errors are also not passed.

What could be the reason?
My codes:

`LoginController.php`

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        return view("auth.login");
    }

    public function loginPost(Request $request)
    {
        $User = User::where("email", $request->get("mail"))->first();

        if($User == null)
        {
            return redirect()->back()->with('emailError', 'No account with this email.')->withInput();
        }

        if(!Hash::check($request->get("password"), $User->password))
        {
            return redirect()->back()->with('passwordError', 'Wrong password')->withInput();
        }

        if($User->activated == 0)
        {
            return redirect()->back()->with('emailError', 'Your account is blocked.')->withInput();
        }

        Auth::login($User, true);
        return redirect()->route("user.home");
    }
}
```

`login.blade.php`

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route("login") }}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail">Mail adress:</label>
                        <input type="email" name="mail" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Your mail" value="{{ old("mail") }}">

                        @if (Session::has('emailError'))
                        <div id="phoneError" class="formError row fg-align-items-center" style="margin-top:5px;">
                            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
                            <span class="errorText">{{ Session::get("emailError") }}</span>
                        </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputNumber" style="margin-top:15px;">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername" placeholder="*****">

                        @if (Session::has('passwordError'))
                        <div id="phoneError" class="formError row fg-align-items-center" style="margin-top:5px;">
                            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
                            <span class="errorText">{{ Session::get("passwordError") }}</span>
                        </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group fg-justify-content-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:15px;width:120px;">Log in</button>
                        <a href="{{ route("register") }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:15px;width:120px;margin-left:20px;">New here?</button></a>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

`web.php` (Routes)

```
Route::get('/login', [App\Http\Controllers\LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('login')->middleware('guest');
Route::post('/login', [App\Http\Controllers\LoginController::class, 'loginPost'])->name('login')->middleware('guest');
```

What is the reason for the malfunction?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me a while ago. Try adding `web` middleware to your route, if I'm not wrong, the routes that doesn't have this middleware doesn't work with sessions, and the errors and other data that you send from the controller are passed with the sessions.

```
Route::get('/login', [App\Http\Controllers\LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('login')->middleware(['guest', 'web']);
Route::post('/login', [App\Http\Controllers\LoginController::class, 'loginPost'])->name('login')->middleware(['guest', 'web']);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it makes no difference ..